# Does decomissioning a node remove data from that node?

Tags: hadoop

In Hadoop, if I decommission a node Hadoop will redistribute the files across the cluster so they are properly replicated.  Will the data be deleted from the decomissioned node?

I am trying to balance the data across the disks on a particular node.  I plan to do this by decomissioning the node and then recomissioning the node.  Do I need to delete the data from that node after decomissioning is complete, or will it be enough to simply recomission it (remove it from the excludes file and run `hadoop dfsadmin -refreshNodes`)?

UPDATE: It worked for me to decomission a node, delete all the data on that node, and then recomission it.

Comment: So, you have multiple disks mounted on a node?

Comment: Yes.  A node has 6 disks.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, data is not removed from a DataNode when you decommission it. Further writes on that DataNode will not be possible though. When you decommission a DataNode, the replicas held by that DataNode are marked as "decommissioned" replicas, which are still eligible for read access.

But why do you want to perform this decomissioning/recomissioning cycle?Why don't you just specify all the disks as a comma separated value to the dfs.data.dir property in your hdfs-site.xml and restart the DataNode daemon. Run the balancer after the restart.

Comment: The balancer balances accross nodes, not on disks within a node.  If a node has 4 disks and those disks fill up, then two more disks are added, there will be disk space issues because the data is unbalanced.  See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1312.

Comment: Yes. It won't. I was assuming that you have all the disks attached to the node, as you didn't specify this in the question. Anyways, you could do it as suggested by @JtheRocker.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop currently doesn't support doing this automatically. But there might be hacks around to do that automatically.

Decommissioning and then replication, will be slow in my opinion, then manually moving blocks across different disks.

You can do the balancing manually though across the disks, something like this -

**1**.Take down the HDFS or only the datanode you are targeting.

**2**.Use the UNIX mv command to move the individual blocks and meta pairs from one directory to another on the host machine. E.g. **move pairs of  blk data file and blk.meta files to accross the disks on the same host.**

**3**.Restart the HDFS or the datanode

[Reference link for the procedure](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#On_an_individual_data_node.2C_how_do_you_balance_the_blocks_on_the_disk.3F)

**Addendum:**
You need to probably move pairs of **blk_*** and **blk_*.meta** files to and from inside the **dfs/current** directory of each data disk. E.g. pair files - blk_3340211089776584759 and blk_3340211089776584759_1158.meta

If you don't want do this manually, you can probably write a custom script to detect how much is occupied in the **dfs/current** directory of the each of your data disks and re-balance them accordingly i.e. move pairs of blk_* and blk_*.meta from one to another.

Comment: I'm aware of this.  It would be nice to have more details about which subfolder to move blk files to.

Comment: I wrote a scala program to do this a week ago but decomissioning and recomissioning seems safer: https://github.com/schmmd/hadoop-balancer

Comment: @schmmd, I'll have a look. Thanks, in the meantime, I have done some edit have a look! Let's find a way together to solve this thing. :)