# Decommission/Recommission Hadoop Node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I can find info regarding the process of decommissioning of a node in hadoop cluster but not what happens to the data in the decommissioned node.

Only info i found is the answer given by Tariq at [Does decomissioning a node remove data from that node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839349/does-decomissioning-a-node-remove-data-from-that-node)

My doubt is regarding the recommission of an old node.

If data is lost, it is same as commissioning a new node. Problem solved.

But, if the data is not lost, when we recommission it, the blocks present in this node become redundant since these blocks were already copied during decommission process. This leads to inconsistency in replicas of the blocks.

How does the hadoop framework takes care of this situation?

Comment: May be it'll process over replicated blocks on recommission. Check for processOverReplicatedBlocksOnReCommission in [this link](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/blockmanagement/BlockManager.java)

Comment: so, whenever a node gets added/removed, it might call processOverReplicatedBlock(). Anyway to validate it?

Comment: May be you can try: hadoop fsck -blocks to get a report